Help, I planted Marigolds and they look like they are dying
Hello, I’m fairly new to gardening and so my wife and I decided to redo our mulch bed and wanted to plant flowers. We found these beautiful marigolds at Home Depot and decided to plant them. However 3 days later, the leaves are wilted and they are leaning dramatically, i don’t know what to do. I put plant food in the mulch bed and watered it in but I’m thinking maybe it’s the soil as well. I don’t know and I don’t want them to die out because they look a mess in front of my home.
Would it also be dependent on what soil they are in? Like I said I am a beginner and don’t know much I just wanted to have some beautiful flowers in my yard not a graveyard 

Can you add a close up of a single plant so we can look at it more closely?  Also can you advise how often and how much you water, and your climate?   I'm not an expert with Marigolds (but I have grown them) - but I wonder if they are suffering from transplant shock (in which case they will probably recover and do fine).

I put some pictures below David and I really hope so because I didn’t mean for them to turn out like this

For next year, try planting your own marigolds from seed. I have much better luck with those than I do with purchased plants. And try not to wait until August to plant them.

Would have been useful to know where you are, but if its summer and temperatures are reasonably high where you are, your marigolds need a good watering every day until they've rooted into the surrounding soil, which will take at last two weeks.

Would you also shade new transplants for a few days, too?

Depends on how hot the temperature is and whether they're in full sun - plants of this size should cope provided they're watered sufficiently, assuming they were in pots and not plant cells, unless the temperature is like over 35 DegC and they're in full sun all day. A lot depends on the local weather/climate. Size of root ball is most important.

I live in Alabama where temps can get to the 90s

@bamboo would cutting off the flowers help? (To channel more back to the rest of the plant?)

Yes, but that's a bit silly at this time of year; fine in the spring or very early summer, but this late in a season its a shame to cut off the flowers when winter approaches. They just need lots and lots of watering...

@Bamboo okay I will keep watering them daily but the good news is that some are actually standing back up and leaves are starting to become full again from watering. I still have 6 of them that are struggling

Im thinking of moving them to a closer location in my mulch bed and laying down compost because that red clay is not helping the struggling ones

To me they look like they are wilting as you have already guessed.  Because they need more water.  Exposing the root-ball (as in one of your photos) is not going to help them.
If the underlying soil is sandy, too well drained, then you need to put some compost around the root ball.  Or have a look at water crystals.
If it is too sunny, then give them some shade.  You can make something up with paper and stakes.   Or have a look at shade coth.

Thank you i will try that as soon as possible

I will look on amazon for some sun shade mini umbrellas to stick into the mulch bed
